# How do I get forms inline with each other?

Tags: php, html, css

This probably seems like a really dumb question, but i am building a website for my school project and i need to get these two forms next to each other rather then having a line break inbetween them:

```html
<div style="display:inline;float:left;?">

  <br>

  <form action="edexcel_maths.php" method="post">
    <input style="display:inline;" type="submit" name="edmathsbutt" class="button" value="Edexcel Maths">
  </form>

  <form action="aqa_physics.php" method="post">
    <input style="display:inline;" type="submit" name="aqaphybutt" class="button" value="AQA Physics">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read the [Guide for Homework Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: inline` style on the forms.

```css
form {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:inline;float:left;?">

  <br>

  <form action="edexcel_maths.php" method="post">
    <input style="display:inline;" type="submit" name="edmathsbutt" class="button" value="Edexcel Maths">
  </form>

  <form action="aqa_physics.php" method="post">
    <input style="display:inline;" type="submit" name="aqaphybutt" class="button" value="AQA Physics">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: perfect, thanks it worked now :) - to other people reading this, who are new to html (me) put the form{} bt in the head style section of your code :)